# Why does my record count increase as my denominator for a division performed in a nested query increases?

Tags: sql, sql-server

In my query I'm trying to calculate the total overtime worked by employees by dividing basic salary by 173(hours in a month) which gives me the hourly rate then dividing the total overtime amount of employee by the hourly rate. To my surprise the record count increases as the number of hours in a month increases, should it not decrease?

Here's my script:

```
select 'Employees that worked more overtime' [CAAT],*
    from (  select H.[Month]
            ,H.[Employee Code]
            ,H.[Department]
            ,H.[Job title]
            ,H.[Surname]
            ,H.[Full Names]
            ,H.[Basic Salary]
            ,R.[Overtime]
            ,H.[Hourly Rate]
            ,round(R.[Overtime] / H.[Hourly Rate],2) [Overtime Hours]
            from (select [Month]
                        ,[Employee Code]
                        ,Department
                        ,[Job title]
                        ,[Surname]
                        ,[Full Names]
                        ,nullif(convert(money,[Amount]),0.00) [Basic Salary]
                        ,nullif(round(convert(money,[Amount]) / 173,2),0.00) [Hourly Rate] 
                            from [Salary DB] 
                                where [Field Desc] = 'ED01-Basic Salary') H

                left join 
                                
                (select [Month]
                        ,[Employee Code]
                        ,nullif(sum(convert(money,[Amount])),0.00) [Overtime] 
                        from [Salary DB]
                            where [Field Desc] in ('ED02-O/Time 1.5','ED02-O/Time 2.0','ED42-Sunday Pay') 
                                group by [Month]
                                        ,[Employee Code]) R 
                                    
                            on H.[Employee Code] = R.[Employee Code]
                                and H.[Month] = R.[Month]) [Data]
                                            
    where [Overtime Hours] > '40'
        Order by [Employee Code], [Month] Desc
```

Comment: I have *assumed* SQL Server here, however, if you are using a different product, such as Azure SQL Database, or Synapse, then please [edit] your question to correct the tags.

Comment: I'm indeed using SQL server.

Comment: What does [[tag:sequel]] (*"a database toolkit for the Ruby programming language that provides abstractions over many SQL RDBMS"*) have to do with the question here? Are you actually looking for a solution in Ruby?

Comment: I'm looking for a solution in SQL, never mind the tags. I'm using ssms 18